# Pandas – Groupby with numerical threshold categories?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a rather complex workflow I tried to simplify as much as possible. Given this `DataFrame`...

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["Johnson", "Female", 1.8, 1, 4],
        ["Johnson", "Female", 1.6, 2, 5],
        ["Johnson", "Female", 1.4, 3, 8],
        ["Johnson", "Female", 1.7, 4, 6],
        ["Johnson", "Male", 1.8, 4, 2],
        ["Johnson", "Male", 2.0, 2, 5],
        ["Johnson", "Male", 2.2, 2, 5],
        ["Smith", "Female", 1.7, 2, 2],
        ["Smith", "Female", 1.5, 4, 1],
        ["Smith", "Male", 1.7, 3, 3],
        ["Smith", "Male", 1.7, 3, 3],
        ["Smith", "Male", 1.9, 4, 3],
        ["Smith", "Male", 1.6, 2, 2],
    ],
    columns=["Family", "Gender", "Height", "Hunger", "Thirst"],
)
```

... my goal is four-fold:

1. Groupby Family and Gender
2. Have different cutoffs / thresholds for the number of people at a certain height (as example <1.7, <2.0)
3. Disregard groupby's with small population size
4. Calculate a "Happiness" score based on my metrics "Hunger" and "Thirst"

Something as follows:

```py
scores = []
min_population_size = 1

# Step 1.
for group, dfg, in df.groupby(["Family", "Gender"]):
    
    # Step 2.
    for threshold in [1.7, 2.0]:
        dfg_threshold = dfg[dfg["Height"] < threshold]
        
        # Step 3. and 4.
        if (count := len(dfg_threshold)) > min_population_size:
            happiness = 1 - (1 / (dfg_threshold["Hunger"].mean() * dfg_threshold["Thirst"].mean()))  # placeholder for complex calculation
        else:
            happiness = None
             
        scores.append([group[0], group[1], threshold, count, happiness])
        
pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=["Family", "Gender", "Height-Threshold", "Count", "Happiness"])
```

This pretty ugly implementation works - but because my real dataset is around 80GB and I have around 500 thresholds, this looping is extremely time-consuming. Is there a way to convert this into a single `groupby` or `apply` function so it can be executed in parallel through Dask or at least sped up in Pandas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a third level to `groupby` and use `pandas.cut` as a bin-discretizer to group by:

```
min_population_size = 1

cutter = pd.cut(df['Height'], [0, 1.7, 2.], right=False)
grouper = df.groupby(['Family', 'Gender', cutter])
# do your calculations...
happiness = 1 - (1 / (grouper["Hunger"].mean() * grouper["Thirst"].mean()))
happiness[grouper.size() <= 1] = None
```

When discretizing into bins, `right=False/True` sets if the bin is treated as right-inclusive or exclusive.

To my knowledge, there is no way to discretize in overlapping bins with pandas without making multiple group-bys and looping over them... Perhaps someone has an idea how to do this with `agg`?
Anyways, here is my approach while trying to reduce to costly loops as much as possible:

```
bins = [1.7, 2.]
# make overlapping cutters and groupers
cutters = [pd.cut(df['Height'], [0, i], right=False) for i in bins]
groupers = [df.groupby(['Family', 'Gender', cttr]) for cttr in cutters]

# do your calculations... this could still take some time. no idea how to avoid this loop...
happiness = [1 - (1 / (grpr["Hunger"].mean() * grpr["Thirst"].mean())) for grpr in groupers]

# this loop should be fairly cheap...
for i in range(len(groupers)):
    happiness[i][groupers[i].size() <= 1] = None
    happiness[i].index.rename(  # this part is fully optional
        'Height-Thresh-{0:.1f}'.format(bins[i]), level=2, inplace=True)
```

The following concatenation should be fairly cheap again:

```
score = pd.concat(happiness, axis=1)
score.index.rename(['Family', 'Gender', 'Height-Threshold'], inplace=True)
```

If you want to have the height-thresh as columns:

```
score = score.unstack(-1).droplevel(axis=1, level=0).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

And probably set some "easier" names to the columns:

```
score.columns = bins
```

Comment: Bins must be non-overlapping in pandas. Thus you'd need to make several cutters.

Comment: Yep, no idea how to solve it without looping. I'll give it a try...

Comment: Thanks for accepting! How is the performance on this one?

Comment: I ran a subsample. It seems like the largest time consumer is my "happiness" calculation which I can't really use an aggregation for. Otherwise using pd.cut is a few ms faster per cycle.

Comment: If you show your full calculations in a follow-up question and post the link here, I might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to figure it out and let you know if I can't speed things up enough.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you can use a vectorized calculation, you should do it.

In your case, you may use `expanding().mean()` within each group, if the heights are sorted, and then select the cut points that you want to report on.

In similar situations where a sort in each group is needed for the calculations, I found that it is a good idea to sort the whole DataFrame once (I know, counter-intuitive since `sort` is O(n log n), but it is still usually faster than sorting within each group).

So how about this:

```
def worker(g, min_population, show_mean=False):
    z = g[['Hunger', 'Thirst']].expanding().mean().rename(columns=lambda x: f'{x}.mean')
    z = z.assign(threshold=g.threshold, count=np.arange(1, g.shape[0] + 1))
    z = z.loc[np.concatenate((z['threshold'].values[:-1] != z['threshold'].values[1:], [True]))]
    z = z.loc[z['count'] >= min_population]
    z['happiness'] = 1 - (1 / (z['Hunger.mean'] * z['Thirst.mean']))
    columns = ['count', 'happiness']
    if show_mean:
        columns = ['Hunger.mean', 'Thirst.mean'] + columns
    return z.set_index('threshold')[columns]

def my_stats(df, thresholds, min_population, show_mean=False):
    res = (df
           .assign(threshold=pd.cut(
               df['Height'], np.concatenate(([-np.Inf], thresholds)),
               labels=thresholds, right=False))
           .dropna(subset=['threshold'])
           .sort_values('Height')
           .groupby(['Family', 'Gender'])
           .aggregate(worker, min_population=min_population, show_mean=show_mean)
          )
    return res
```

Given the DataFrame in **your example**:

```
my_stats(df, thresholds=[1.7, 2.0], min_population=2)

Out[ ]:
                          count  happiness
Family  Gender threshold                  
Johnson Female 1.7            2   0.938462
               2.0            4   0.930435
Smith   Female 2.0            2   0.777778
        Male   2.0            4   0.878788
```

Or, if you are interested in showing the means that were used in your calculations:

```
my_stats(df, thresholds=[1.7, 2.0], min_population=2, show_mean=True)

Out[ ]:
                          Hunger.mean  Thirst.mean  count  happiness
Family  Gender threshold                                            
Johnson Female 1.7                2.5         6.50      2   0.938462
               2.0                2.5         5.75      4   0.930435
Smith   Female 2.0                3.0         1.50      2   0.777778
        Male   2.0                3.0         2.75      4   0.878788
```

**Speed test**

```
%%time
thresholds = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0, 3, size=500))
my_stats(df, thresholds=thresholds, min_population=2)

Out[ ]:
CPU times: user 225 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 225 ms
Wall time: 224 ms
                          count  happiness
Family  Gender threshold                  
Coulson Female 0.331058       2   0.928571
               0.349368       3   0.931818
               0.352899       4   0.960000
               0.364010       5   0.958333
               0.380945       6   0.959596
...                         ...        ...
Ward    Male   2.912417    7349   0.950410
               2.928181    7350   0.950410
               2.972472    7351   0.950402
               2.986354    7352   0.950401
               2.992616    7353   0.950404
```